# How can I use libgit2sharp to change the working directory?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I've been trying to change the working directory using `libgit2sharp` and so far I haven't worked out how to do it. `Checkout` doesn't appear to do it, `Reset` is available but `ResetOptions.Hard` is not. Has it not been implemented or is there a way that I'm missing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, LibGit2Sharp implemenation of Checkout only deals with moving `HEAD`. As well, Reset Hard is not implemented yet.

Fortunately, the `Checkout` **[feature](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/checkout.h)** has been added to libgit2 **[few weeks ago](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commits/development/include/git2/checkout.h)**.

It's only a matter of time (and a little bit of code :-) ) before this feature is made available to LibGit2Sharp.

### Update:

The `vNext` development branch has been updated. It's now possible to perform a **Hard Reset**. (e.g. `repo.Reset(ResetOptions.Hard, "HEAD~3");` )

For more information, one can peek at the changes **[here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/0580f3688eaf128c484675eb67c8880a1d45c9f8)**.

Comment: Since people find this by just googling for how to hard-reset your working directory: use this instead of "HEAD~3" to reset your current workspace to the last commit shared between your local repo and the upstream:                Commit originHeadCommit = repo.ObjectDatabase.FindMergeBase(repo.Branches["origin/master"].Tip, repo.Head.Tip);